# App not occupying complete screen in iphone X simulator in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, iphone, view, xcode9, iphone-x

With the release of Xcode 9, we are able to test UI of our app on iPhone X simulator. When I ran my app on iPhone X simulator, it does not occupy complete screen. There is space left on the top and bottom of the Apps View.

Can anyone please tell how to remove that space, I am already using auto layouts in my app. I am attaching the screenshot of my app.

[image]

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use a launch storyboard rather than a launch image. That way your app will automatically support new devices and screen sizes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add Splash screen/Launch Image for iPhone X in xcode 9.
iPhone X launch image's dimensions are `1125 x 2436`

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the new feature **Safe Area** of **Xcode 9** to handle user interface design for **iPhone-X**.

It is required to handle user interface design for **iPhone-X**. Here is basic guideline for How to design user interface for **iPhone-X** using Safe Area Layout

Here is the developer guidelines of apple [IPhone-X Development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqdUm.png)

You can solve this by 2 ways

**1.** Uncheck use safe area support

[image]

**2.** If you are using `Autolayout` adjust your `toplayout` constraint value as that achive FullScreen